# $_SESSION to setcookie in PHP

Tags: php, session-cookies

Until now, I was always using PHP's `$_SESSION` for login and shopping cart storage on my online store. Can I safely change the shopping cart storage to PHP's `setcookie`, since I want my customers to keep their shopping carts for a long time? I'm worried about the customers who doesn't have cookies enabled. Are there any Internet users, who doesn't have cookies enabled? Or should I use `$_SESSION` as a backup method - for an example, to save them both with session and cookies?

Comment: *doesn't have cookies enabled* You answered your own question. <-

Comment: I think if you want to save them longer time you would have to save them in a DB

Comment: Very good idea, this way I'll keep track on my saved carts. But how do I identify each visitor? I think `session_id` won't work.

Comment: I can save each cart into the DB, and `setcookie` the cart id for future fetching. But then again I'll worry about the non-cookie browsers. I'm looking for the best way.

Comment: There is where you need a login :D So 1. Login = -> Shopping cart saved in DB 2. no login = -> Shopping cart only saved in session

Comment: Of course, I have login system, but non-logged customers can also make an order (guest order). BTW, my correct worry is about the non-javascript browsers, are there any?

Comment: yeah of cores I would also worry about 0.000025% of all users which doesn't have ecmascript enabled. (Just to show you a few bigger sites what they do if you don't have JS enabled; disable it and go on: maps.google.com or yahoo.com or amazon.com you will get huge differences!) Also as I said if the user is logged in you can save it in the DB with user ID and if not you can only save it in session, that's how most sites work

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done for now. Basically, the function `retrieveCart()` retrieves the `$_SESSION` variable, and `updateCart()` updates it. It recognises each cart by the `LastInsertId()` of the carts table.

**functions.php:**

```
function retrieveCart() {
    global $DBH;

    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        if(isset($_COOKIE['cart_id'])) {
            $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT content FROM carts_retail WHERE id=:id LIMIT 0,1");
            $STH->execute(array(
                'id' => $_COOKIE['cart_id']
            ));

            if($STH->rowCount() == 1) {
                while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
                    $_SESSION['cart'] = unserialize($row['content']);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO carts_retail (content, customer_id) VALUES (:content, :customer_id)");
            $STH->execute(array(
                'content' => serialize($_SESSION['cart']),
                'customer_id' => (isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : 0)
            ));

            setcookie('cart_id', $DBH->LastInsertId(), strtotime('+30 DAYS'));
        }
    }
}

function updateCart($action = NULL, $content = NULL) {
    global $DBH;

    if($action == 'add') {
        if(is_numeric($content['id']) && is_numeric($content['qty']) && strlen($content['size']) > 0) {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$content['id']] = array('qty' => $content['qty'], 'size' => $content['size']);
        }
    }

    if($action == 'delete') {
        if(is_numeric($content['id'])) {
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$content['id']]);
        }
    }

    $STH = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE carts_retail SET content=:content, customer_id=:customer_id WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1");
    $STH->execute(array(
        'id' => $_COOKIE['cart_id'],
        'content' => serialize($_SESSION['cart']),
        'customer_id' => (isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : 0)
    ));
}
```

**cart.php:**

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    if($_POST['action'] == 'add' || $_POST['action'] == 'delete') {
        updateCart($_POST['action'], array(
            'id' => (isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : NULL),
            'qty' => (isset($_POST['qty']) ? $_POST['qty'] : NULL),
            'size' => (isset($_POST['size']) ? $_POST['size'] : NULL)
        ));

        header('Location: /cart');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer to your question but a clarification because it seems that you have some problems with the difference of `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE` - `$_SESSION` uses `Cookies` per default, lifetime is the current browser session. An unique session id is stored on the client's browser cookies - with this session id PHP automatically find the corresponding session values to this id. Basically stored in a simple serialized file in a tmp folder.
So, as you can see, SESSION could never be (if you store session id in cookie as it is in PHP per default) a fallback for disabled cookies.
Just to make it clear for you.

Comment: The problem was that since I've used `$_SESSION`, when I re-open my browser, the cart was disappearing. After I've used `setcookie` for the cart ID and connected it with the database, it stays for 30 days, which was my goal.

Comment: Yup,just wanted to clear that PHP behaviour for you because it seemed to me that you don't know that SESSION ID also stored via cookies. Your general idea of storing the data in cookies for longer than a browser session is correct.

Comment: So, for how long does the session id is being kept in the cookie? Currently, I save the cart id for 30 days. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, weird. I do this: `<?php session_start(); echo session_id(); ?>`, copy the session id, and when I re-open my browser it's different. Are you sure that it's being saved with a cookie? Thanks.

Comment: As i said, the session id is stored in a cookie, as long as the current browser session is alive. If you restart your browser than it's another id. This means, a `$_SESSION` lifetime is equal a browser session. I don'T want to clarify how you should handle a login with cookies. Only point was "how the session work".